# Updating a database from an Excel spreadsheet in .NET

Tags: vb.net, excel, teradata

Can Teradata tables be updated in an VB.NET application by reading an Excel spreadsheet and pulling certain values from certain columns? If so how?

Answer (score -1):

Yes.

[This link](http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/srcview.aspx?dir=MSOffice&file=CopyData-SqlToExcel-TwoOledbConnections.cs) shows how to read from a server database and update Excel, via ADO.NET and two OleDb connections.

It should be easy to modify that code to do the reverse. ; you'd just need to swap the connection strings shown in that code, so that the source is Excel, and the destination is your Teradata db.

There are some Excel-specific things in the queries, but you get the idea.

**NB:** This is not Excel Automation. It uses ADO.NET to read/update an Excel sheet.  You don't need Excel to be installed on the machine in order to do these queries.

Comment: Well.. it was three years prior that it was answer. I am fully aware that the comment I am replying to is 2 years old. Maybe in two years someone can comment here again. Anyway, here it is from Wayback Machine: http://web.archive.org/web/20090108093036/http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/srcview.aspx?dir=MSOffice&file=CopyData-SqlToExcel-TwoOledbConnections.cs